# Php procedure sqlsrv script with SQL Server error

Tags: php, sql-server, syntax-error

I would also need help with the procedure. I have written this code in PHP

```
    
$sql = "EXEC EXPORT_DAT @id_w = '".$id_w."'";

$stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($link, $sql);

if (!sqlsrv_execute($stmt)) {
echo die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));

}

else 

{

while($row  = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC)) {

$value[] = $row;

}

echo json_encode($value);

}
```

but the procedure returns this error.

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 01000 [SQLSTATE] => 01000 [1] => 0 [code] => 0 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]CREATE TABLE tbl_point_50000263 (id varchar (max)) [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]CREATE TABLE tbl_point_50000263 (id varchar (max)) ) )

I don't know what can be wrong because C# it works.

Thank you

Comment: It's dificult without the actual code of the stored p[rocedure, but you need to use parameterized statement (e.g. `$sql = "EXEC EXPORT_DAT @id_w = ?`) and pass the parameter's value in the `sqlsrv_execute` call.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the script, the output is OK, but the procedure will not run.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I fixed the script, the output is OK, but the procedure will not run.

```
$sql = "EXEC EXPORT_DAT @id_w = ?";
$id_w=50000263; 
$stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($link, $sql, array(&$id_w));
if( !$stmt ) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
else 
{
echo "OK";
}
sqlsrv_close($link);
```

Run the C # procedure

Comment: You need to execute the statement. Simply replace `$stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($link, $sql, array(&$id_w));` with `$stmt = sqlsrv_query($link, $sql, array($id_w));`.